# How to navigate from a custom collection view to a TabbarController in swift 4?

Tags: swift

I have tried this but didn't work for me:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
   cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
   cell?.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        print("swift")
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Action") as! UIViewController
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please elaborate what part doesn't work. Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help you formulate a good question.

Comment: what do you mean with _didn't work_?

Comment: `self.navigationController` might be `nil`, so `pushViewController` is never executed on it. You might want to look into segues instead of manually pushing view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing to a **UIViewController**.

You might be pushing to a `UIViewController` inside `UITabbarController`. To navigate to `UITabbarController` you need to instantiate the `UITabbarController` and push to it.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBar") as! UITabBarController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*//Get reference to your tab bar.*
let tabBar:UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

let navInTab:UINavigationController = tabBar.viewControllers?[1] as! UINavigationController

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ControllersName") as? ControllersType
navInTab.pushViewController(destinationViewController!, animated: true)

*//To whichever index you want to navigate.*

tabBar.selectedIndex = 1

**Hope this helps.**
```

Answer (score -1):

You should segue to the tab bar controller, not the UIViewController contained by it.

An easy way to do it is setting a segue using your storyboard and call performSegue when you want to initiate the transition.

First set the storyboard as follows:

[image: Segue to tab bar]
Then you may call `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logInSegue", sender: self)`

(`logInSegue` is the name of my segue but obviously you should change it to your segue identifier you have set in your storyboard)